# raspi not seeing teensy, udev rules probably at fault

Tags: raspberry-pi, udev

I am pretty deep into this now and operating at about 50% understanding. We have a Raspi 3B+ running Ubuntu 20.04 for Raspi. We have a Teensy 3.7. They are connected together with a USB cable. I know that the Teensy is getting power.

This is the rule that I am being told to use:

```
KERNEL=="ttyACM?", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0478", ATTRS{serial}=="000F0B8C", MODE="0666" SYMLINK+="linobase"
```

#### Not sure what udev rules do exactly

I have the feeling the the udev rule is not "matching" and that's why it is not creating the symlink. But I really am not at all sure. But honestly I don't really understand udev. I am just kind of plowing through with "common sense' which is not working for me.

#### Cable?

I was also suspecting it might be the usb cable? As I understand it many usb cables are "power only". However, the problem didn't go away when I used a "known good" data USB cable.

#### Code 43?

There may be an esoteric problem known as the "Code 43" problem that is in play here - see pjrc.com/teensy/troubleshoot.html. Anyone know anything about it?

Comment: You may want to ask this over on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com. Ignoring the udev rule, does the `/dev/ttyACM*` show up when you attach the teensy? What do you see in the kernel log when you plug it in (include the output in your question)? Run `journalctl -kfl` in a terminal, and then watch the output when you attach the device.

Comment: Why would a USB device end up as /dev/ttyACM* vs /dev/ttyUSB* (by the way?)

Comment: https://rfc1149.net/blog/2013/03/05/what-is-the-difference-between-devttyusbx-and-devttyacmx/

Comment: Does the device show up if you do `sudo lsusb -v` ? You can maybe check your vendor and product identifiers.

Comment: I am also suspecting it might be the usb cable? As I understand it many usb cables are "power only". But there's no way to check whether the cable itself is good for connecting the teensy to the raspi. Is that correct?

Comment: There may be an esoteric problem known as the "Code 43" problem that is in play here - see https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/troubleshoot.html. Anyone know anything about it?

Comment: You don't appear to have answered either larsks' or my question? You are also apparently referring to a Windows code 43 issue when talking about Linux udev rules?

Comment: Sorry @MarkSetchell ... I didn't know that Code 43 is windows specific. I took the robot to my hardware friend who is a windows guy and he claimed that he fixed it because of Code 43. When I get it back I will try. What I did do before I took it to him was replace the cable with a known good usb data cable and that didn't help. And then I tried attaching it directly to my mac (Dont have windows) and it was not recognized at all! So maybe it's not actually fixed. Was your question about journalctl -fkl meant to be run on the pi? I assume so? Once I have it the hardware back in hand I will try!